# What is the best way to run python scripts on a Google Compute Engine on a schedule?

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I am trying to schedule a python script to run on my GCE machine running ubuntu 18.04. Some points I am considering:

1. The VM is running 24/7 as it is on the free tier
2. I went through the following docs https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule and it suggests a way to start and stop the VM using cloud functions and scheduler but i am looking to run my python script on the running machine
3. I have to run it on GCE as cannot use cloud functions/app engine /cloud runs as the script runs for around 1 hour 30 mins which would cause a timeout on all the other compute options.

I am new to ubuntu and GCP so excuse me if there is a trivial solution i am missing.

Any pointers to trigger specific scripts on GCE using cloud functions would also be helpful as i might need to turn on and off the VM if i upgrade to a higher tier

Comment: Create a Python/Flask app, give it an HTTP endpoint and call that endpoint with Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley , You suggest
`from import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
     """ My Code """""
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 5000)`

Comment: Yes, something like that should work. The next step is to be able to process the endpoint call from Cloud Scheduler and verify the Identity Token to protect the API.

Comment: It could be easier to use only Ubuntu and run your script on schedule by using Cron. Have a look at the documentation  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto   and example https://medium.com/@thucnc/schedule-tasks-to-run-regularly-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-cronta-13227d669256.